# How to correctly synchronize on a LinkedList?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I'm editing a `LinkedList` and getting warnings because my synchronized variable is not final. How do I make this thread safe?

I am attempting to synchronize on a `LinkedList` and I am getting a warning from my IDE stating that synchronizing on a non-final field is unlikely to be useful.

I have tried a private lock object, however when I synchronize using that I get the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`

```
    protected List<ServerDataEvent> _queue = new LinkedList<>();

    synchronized (_queue) {
        while(_queue.isEmpty()) {
            try {_queue.wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        dataEvent = _queue.remove(0);
    }
```

I'd like to make this thread safe, but I'm not able to get the program to work unless I synchronize on the `LinkedList`. Can anyone give pointers on what I need to do to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: If you're getting warnings because it's not final, have you considered... making it final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am attempting to synchronize on a LinkedList and I am getting a warning from my IDE stating that synchronizing on a non-final field is unlikely to be useful.

Just declare the variable to be `final`.

The problem that if something assigns a new value to a field, then threads that use the variable to synchronize may end up using a different object.  If they do that, they *may not be* synchronizing correctly.

(Perhaps you think that declaring the variable as `final` means that you can't modify the list.  That's not true.  You can add and remove elements to a `final` list.  You just cannot assign a new value to the *variable*; i.e. make it point to a different list instance.)

> I have tried a private lock object, however when I synchronize using that I get the following exception: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

That is a *different* problem.

What is most likely happening is that a thread is calling `wait` or `notify` on an  object when it does not hold the object mutex.  You will get that no matter what type of object you use as the lock.

Comment: Ah I see- I thought declaring it as final would prevent modification, so that's why I didn't set it. Thanks for clearing that up!